# Mimic Python's NoneType

Tags: python, metaclass, nonetype

I'm creating several classes to use them as state flags (this is more of an exercise, though I'm going to use them in a real project), just like we use `None` in Python, i.e.

```
... some_var is None ...
```

`NoneType` has several special properties, most importantly it's a singleton, that is there can't be more than one `NoneType` instance during any interpreter session, and its instances (`None` objects) are immutable. I've come up with two possible ways to implement somewhat similar behaviour in pure Python and I'm eager to know which one looks better from the architectural standpoint.

### 1. Don't use instances at all.

The idea is to have a metaclass, that produces immutable classes. The classes are prohibited to have instances.

```
class FlagMetaClass(type):
    def __setattr__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise TypeError("{} class is immutable".format(self))

    def __delattr__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__setattr__()

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__name__


class BaseFlag(object):
    __metaclass__ = FlagMetaClass

    def __init__(self):
        raise TypeError("Can't create {} instances".format(type(self)))

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(type(self))


class SomeFlag(BaseFlag):
    pass
```

And we get the desired behaviour

```
a = BaseFlag
a is BaseFlag  # -> True
a is SomeFlag  # -> False
```

Obviously any attempt to set attributes on these classes will fail (of course there are several hacks to overcome this, but the direct way is closed). And the classes themselves are unique objects loaded in a namespace.

### 2. A proper singleton class

```
class FlagMetaClass(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(FlagMetaClass, cls).__call__()
        return cls._instances[cls] # This may be slightly modified to 
                                   # raise an error instead of returning
                                   # the same object, e.g.
    # def __call__(cls):
    #     if cls in cls._instances:
    #         raise TypeError("Can't have more than one {} instance".format(cls))
    #     cls._instances[cls] = super(FlagMetaClass, cls).__call__()
    #     return cls._instances[cls]

    def __setattr__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise TypeError("{} class is immutable".format(self))

    def __delattr__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.__setattr__()

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__name__


class BaseFlag(object):
    __metaclass__ = FlagMetaClass
    __slots__ = []

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(type(self))


class SomeFlag(BaseFlag):
    pass
```

Here the `Flag` classes are real singletons. This particular implementation doesn't raise an error when we try to create another instance, but returns the same object (though it's easy to alter this behaviour). Both classes and instances can't be directly modified. The point is to create an instance of each class upon import like it's done with `None`.

Both approaches give me somewhat immutable unique objects that can be used for comparison just like the `None`. To me the second one looks more `NoneType`-like, since `None` is an instance, but I'm not sure that it's worth the increase in idealogical complexity. Looking forward to hear from you.

Comment: If you're just looking for state flags then why try: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34 (I presume you're using python 2.x).

Comment: @Dunes a nice link, thank you.

Comment: Another possibility for "named singletons" is demonstrated in sqlalchemy's `symbol` class: https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/src/838ce5bbad5a88316fa033884ad2b6e629801991/lib/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py?at=master#langhelpers.py-1187 That maybe worth a look at it ...

Comment: Better to use a class, because if one of your flags was to be deepcopy-ed, you'd loose the singleton-like reference, whereas deepcopy outputs the same reference if the input is a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, it's an interesting exercise.  But when you say "though I'm going to use them in a real project" then you lose me.

If the real project is highly unPythonic (using traits or some other package to emulate static typing, using `__slots__` to keep people from falling on sharp objects, etc.) -- well, I've got nothing for you, because I've got no use for that, but others do.

If the real project is Pythonic, then do the simplest thing possible.

Your "not use instances at all" answer is the correct one here, but you don't need to do a lot of class definition, either.

For example, if you have a function that could accept None as a real parameter, and you want to tell if the parameter has been defaulted, then just do this:

```
class NoParameterGiven:
    pass

def my_function(my_parameter=NoParameterGiven):
    if my_parameter is NoParameterGiven:
        <do all my default stuff>
```

That class is so cheap, there's no reason even to share it between files.  Just create it where you need it.

Your state classes are a different story, and you might want to use something like that [enum module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34) that @Dunes mentioned -- it has some nice features.

OTOH, if you want to keep it really simple, you could just do something like this:

```
class MyStates:
    class State1: pass
    class State2: pass
    class State3  pass
```

You don't need to instantiate anything, and you can refer to them like this: `MyStates.State1`.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. I'm going to wait a bit before accepting it in case someone comes up with another one.